# Use a calculator to approximate $\int_0^{7\pi} \sqrt{5-4\cos(t)}dt$ to four decimal places

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Use a calculator to approximate $\int_0^{7\pi} \sqrt{5-4\cos(t)}dt$ to four decimal places

Can somebody explain what this means? Do they want me to use a series expansion or something?? What are some ways this question could be interpreted and could I have a bit help getting through it??

Maybe I'm suppose to use Simpsons rule? I feel like if that were so they would have explicitly said so..

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think they just want you to use a calculator, see ex https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+7pi+sqrt%285-4cost%29dt

Comment: They want you to find $46.7771$. My calculator Casio fx 570 ES plus does this approximations

Answer (score 2):

I think you are just supposed to use any approximation method that yields that particular accuracy, for instance Simpon's composite method. It may be beneficial if you take into consideration that
$$
\int_0^{7 \pi} \sqrt{5 - 4\cos t}dt = 7 \int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{5 - 4\cos t}dt.
$$

If you choose Simpson's method with a certain step $h$, you know that the error satisfies
$$
|E(h)|=\frac{\pi h^4 |f''''(\xi)|}{180}\leq \frac{7 \pi h^4}{80},
$$
and you can choose a value for $h$ in such a way that the answer has four correct decimal digits. This will however implicate using a few hundred points... I hope the calculator is a figure of speech and you can use a computer!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need hundreds of intervals to compute
$$I=\int_0^{7 \pi } \sqrt{5-4 \cos (t)} \, dt$$
Define $f(t)= \sqrt{5-4 \cos (t)}$
$$I_n=\frac{7 \pi  \left(\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} f\left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{2} (f(0)+f(\pi ))\right)}{n}$$
for $n=7$ I got $|I-I_7|<\frac{1}{10^4}$

Comment: @Rafaelle Are you using an "a priori" estimate, or just comparing with the exact result?

Comment: Just comparing with the result. It is a "lucky" function